# Laravel Eloquent: Apply "with where" filter on primary statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Issue:
I am using eloquent to pull students from a database where they have specific status and registration date values. They must also only be shown if sub-table data as specific column data as well.
The issue is that Laravel is breaking it up into multiple queries and the "with" (eager loading) tables are only getting filtered after the fact.

In other words, instead of (pseudo sql):

```
SELECT all students WHERE 
status IN (1,4,6,7) 
AND (YEAR(registration_date)<=2020 OR YEAR(registration_date) IS NULL) 
AND YEAR(commencement_date)>=2020
AND (YEAR(completion_date)>=2020 OR YEAR(estimated_completion_date)>=2020)
```

Its pushing out 4 separate sql statements (refer to 'resulting SQL' below) where its only applying the status / registration_date filter on students, and separately the other filters down the line which causes the actual row results to be incorrect (displaying more than they should).

I would just use `DB::table / DB:raw` - but then on the blade end of things, I cant pull sub-child data because its no longer in a hierarchal structure.

Code:

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $students = $bursary_administrator->students()->whereIn('status',[1,4,6,7])
        ->whereHas('bursaries', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereYear('registration_date','<=',$request->year)
                ->orWhereNull('registration_date');
        })
        ->with(['bursaries','bursaries.enrolments','bursaries.enrolments.courses' => function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->whereYear('commencement_date', '<=', $request->year)
                ->where(function ($query) use ($request){
                    $query->whereYear('completion_date', '>=', $request->year)
                        ->whereYear('estimated_completion_date', '>=', $request->year,'or');
                });
        }])
        ->orderBy('student_name')->orderBy('student_middle_names')->orderBy('student_surname')->get();
    Log::debug(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Resulting SQL:

```
local.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select `students`.*, `bursary_administrator_student`.`bursary_administrator_id` as `pivot_bursary_administrator_id`, `bursary_administrator_student`.`student_id` as `pivot_student_id`, `bursary_administrator_student`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `bursary_administrator_student`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `students` inner join `bursary_administrator_student` on `students`.`id` = `bursary_administrator_student`.`student_id` where `bursary_administrator_student`.`bursary_administrator_id` = ? and `status` in (?, ?, ?, ?) and exists (select * from `student_bursaries` where `students`.`id` = `student_bursaries`.`student_id` and (year(`registration_date`) <= ? or `registration_date` is null)) order by `student_name` asc, `student_middle_names` asc, `student_surname` asc',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 1,
      1 => 1,
      2 => 4,
      3 => 6,
      4 => 7,
      5 => '2020',
    ),
    'time' => 6.69,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `student_bursaries` where `student_bursaries`.`student_id` in (1, 3, 14, 20, 24, 25, 29, 41, 42, 44, 49, 51, 53, 55, 56, 62, 64, 65, 72, 75, 76, 80, 81, 85, 94, 98, 100, 106, 111, 112, 133, 138, 139, 141, 156, 157, 169, 170, 180, 199, 203, 210, 213, 214, 217, 219, 221, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243, 246, 249, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 265, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 297, 299, 300, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 2.41,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `student_bursary_enrolments` where `student_bursary_enrolments`.`student_bursary_id` in (1, 3, 14, 20, 24, 25, 29, 41, 42, 44, 49, 51, 53, 55, 56, 62, 64, 65, 72, 75, 76, 80, 81, 85, 94, 98, 100, 106, 111, 112, 133, 138, 139, 141, 156, 157, 169, 170, 180, 199, 203, 210, 213, 214, 217, 219, 221, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 243, 246, 249, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 263, 265, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 297, 299, 300, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
    ),
    'time' => 2.41,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `student_bursary_enrolment_courses` where `student_bursary_enrolment_courses`.`student_bursary_enrolment_id` in (1, 3, 12, 18, 19, 21, 22, 27, 28, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 48, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 57, 64, 65, 66, 67, 72, 75, 76, 77, 81, 82, 85, 93, 96, 98, 99, 104, 110, 111, 130, 134, 135, 136, 138, 152, 153, 154, 164, 165, 175, 180, 181, 187, 193, 194, 195, 196, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 247, 248, 252, 253, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 409, 411, 413, 414, 415, 417, 418, 419, 424, 429, 431, 432, 433, 436, 442, 443, 445, 447, 448, 450, 452, 453, 456, 457, 466, 467, 468, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485) and year(`commencement_date`) <= ? and (year(`completion_date`) >= ? or year(`estimated_completion_date`) >= ?)',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => '2020',
      1 => '2020',
      2 => '2020',
    ),
    'time' => 2.85,
  ),
)
```

Blade / View:

```
<tbody>
@if ($students)
    @php($row_count=0)
    @foreach ($students as $student)
        @php($row_count++)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$row_count}}</td>
            <td>{{$student->student_name .' '. $student->student_middle_names .' '. $student->student_surname}}</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                @if ($student->bursaries)
                    <table class="subtable">
                        @foreach ($student->bursaries as $bursary)
                            @if ($bursary->enrolments)
                                @foreach ($bursary->enrolments as $enrolment)
                                    @if ($enrolment->courses)
                                        @foreach ($enrolment->courses as $course)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$enrolment->academic_institution->academic_institution .' - '. $course->course}}</td>
                                                <td class="f114">{{__($course->current_year)}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @else
                                        <tr><td>Error: No courses</td></tr>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                <tr><td>Error: No enrolments</td></tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                @else
                    Error: No bursaries
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif

</tbody>
```

Comment: Apart from your answer `AND YEAR(commencement_date)>=2020` clause looks redundant in your query

Comment: Hi Khalid, not sure what you mean 'apart from your answer'? ```AND YEAR(commencement_date)>=2020``` is not redundant as its filtering to only courses which have a commencement_date >= 2020, along with completion_date / estimated_completion_date / registration_date - thats 4 different date fields altogether.